# Error: A value of type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<ChartData>', trying to create a Chart with a list of Strings,

Tags: list, flutter, charts

I'm trying to create a graph and i don't know how to set values on this graph (I know how to set the values manually but i created a field in firestore that receives the value of x and y of the graph when you click on a button ), i'm using SyncFusion Flutter Chart (if you have any another idea to solve my problem feel free to say) and i'm trying to add the values ( String ) to the list and for that i Created in firestore when you click on the button (ChartData(x,y)) so all i need is add this string to the list of type ChartData, and for that i'm trying to use decode and split but now returned this error and i don't know how to solve. i'm sorry for the long text.

```
    List<ChartData> convert(String input) {
      List<ChartData> output;
      try {
        output = json.decode(input);
        return output;
      } catch (err) {
        print('The input is not a string representation of a list');
        return [ChartData(0, 0)];
      }
    }
   List<ChartData> testim = testefinal.split(',');
    final List<ChartData> list1 = convert(testefinal);
    final List<ChartData> chartData = list1;
```

```
Error: A value of type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<ChartData>'.
```

Full Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mood3/telas/animacao.dart';
import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import '../model/GraphMood.dart';


class Graph extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<Graph> createState() => _GraphState();
}




class _GraphState extends State<Graph> {

  TooltipBehavior? _tooltipBehavior;
  DateTime ntpTime = DateTime.now();
String testefinal = '';
  _loadNTPTime() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    setState(() async {
      ntpTime = await NTP.now();
    });
  }
  Future _recuperarNome() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth2 = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth2.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await db.collection('usuarios')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get();
    Map<String, dynamic> dss = ds.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    setState((){
      testefinal = dss["moodGraph"];
    });
    print(testefinal);
  }

  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  initState(){
    _recuperarNome();
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    super.initState();
    _loadNTPTime();
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ChartData> convert(String input) {
      List<ChartData> output;
      try {
        output = json.decode(input);
        return output;
      } catch (err) {
        print('The input is not a string representation of a list');
        return [ChartData(0, 0)];
      }
    }
   List<ChartData> testim = testefinal.split(',');
    final List<ChartData> list1 = convert(testefinal);
    final List<ChartData> chartData = list1;



    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(

                    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                    // Chart title
                    title: ChartTitle(text: 'Mood Chart'),
                    // Enable legend
                    legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
                    // Enable tooltip
                    tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,

                    series: <ChartSeries>[
                      // Renders line chart
                      LineSeries<ChartData, int>(
                          dataSource: chartData,
                          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x.toInt(),
                          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y
                      )
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final double x;
  final double y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, output = json.decode(input) as List();

Comment: it's not converting :C